# Pyspark streaming from Kafka source and save to hdfs

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I have a kafka topic and I want to use PySpark streaming for reading data from a kafka producer, doing some transformation, and saving to HDFS. I want data to be done every time catching it from a kafka source. I think the problem is in my "update" function. Below is my code:

```
orders_df = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_bootstrap_servers) \
    .option("subscribe", kafka_topic_name) \
    .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
    .load()

orders_df1 = orders_df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)", "timestamp")


stock_price_schema = types.StructType([
    types.StructField("symbol", types.StringType(), True),
    types.StructField("date", types.DateType(), True),
    types.StructField("open", types.DoubleType(), True),
    types.StructField("high", types.DoubleType(), True),
    types.StructField("low", types.DoubleType(), True),
    types.StructField("close", types.DoubleType(), True),
    types.StructField("volume", types.IntegerType(), True)
])

orders_df2 = orders_df1\
    .select(from_json(col("value"), stock_price_schema)\
    .alias("orders"), "timestamp")
    
# orders_df3 = orders_df2.select("orders.*", "timestamp")

stock_df = orders_df2.select("orders.*")
    
# Write final result into console for debugging purpose
orders_agg_write_stream = stock_df \
    .writeStream \
    .trigger(processingTime='5 seconds') \
    .outputMode("update") \
    .option("truncate", "false")\
    .format("console") \
    .start()


def update(stock_df):
    
    if stock_df.count() == 0:
        return
    
    for row in stock_df.rdd.collect():
        
        symbol = row["symbol"]
        df_new = stock_df[stock_df["symbol"] == symbol]
        df_old = spark.read.parquet(f"data/pq/{symbol}/")
        
        df_new = df_old.union(df_new).distinct()
        df_new.repartition(4).write.parquet(f"data/pq/{symbol}/")

update(orders_agg_write_stream)
orders_agg_write_stream.awaitTermination()

print("Stream Data Processing Application Completed.")
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing - you can't simply do `.rdd.collect` on the stream - stream by definition is infinite.  Instead you need to perform your logic on the microbatches that will be called if you use [foreachBatch function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#foreachbatch) that exists exactly for that reason.

Also, I would recommend to use [Delta Lake](https://delta.io/) data format instead of plain Parquet (Delta Lake is also built on top of Parquet, btw).  There are few reasons for that:

- if you stream from Kafka, you will create a lot of small files, and listing them when reading Parquet will be quite expensive. Delta solves that by using transaction log
- you will get transactionality for your data - consumers won't read the partial results
- Delta has built-in [merge/update/delete capabilities](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-update.html), also transactional, so it could be more efficient to express your logic using built-in functionality instead of rewriting all data again & again.